# How do I recover my containers from previous install?

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I wish to get back my container from a previous installation of Windows 7, already reinstalled Docker Toolbox but I have no idea how to recover my old containers or where they are.

Answer (score 1):

See https://forums.docker.com/t/where-are-images-stored/9794/9

They should be stored under `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks` on the host machine. I haven't worked with Docker under Windows recently so this information might be outdated.